# Matching and returning value using wildcard with regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Let's say I have a sting with a number of words separated by spaces.  Each word has a single digit number after it.  If I have a word, is it possible to find the word in the string and return it along with the number after it?  (using Ruby)

For example:

```
string = "test0 chance1 already0 again4"
word = "chance"
```

How can I get a return value of "chance1"?

Update:

```
/word\d+/.match(string) returns "chance1"
```

This seems to be working.

Comment: While what you are asking is more than possible, it would help if you provided what language you want your answer in.  Capturing the match isn't language agnostic.

Comment: The title and a tag specify Ruby, so I'm guessing that's is what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample and update don't work:

```
Update:

/string\d+/.match(word) returns "chance1"
This seems to be working.
```

Dumping it into irb shows:

```
>> string = "test0 chance1 already0 again4" #=> "test0 chance1 already0 again4"
>> word = "chance" #=> "chance"
>> /string\d+/.match(word) #=> nil
```

so that isn't working.

I'd recommend:

```
>> Hash[*string.scan(/(\w+)(\d)/).flatten]['chance'] #=> "1"
```

or

```
>> hash = Hash[*string.scan(/(\w+)(\d)/).flatten]
>> hash['chance'] #=> "1"
>> hash['test'] #=> "0"
>> hash['again'] #=> "4"
```

It works by scanning for the words ending with a digit, and grabbing the word and the digit separately. String.scan will return an array of arrays, where each inner array contains the groups matched.

```
>> string.scan(/(\w+)(\d)/) #=> [["test", "0"], ["chance", "1"], ["already", "0"], ["again", "4"]]
```

Then I flatten it to get a list of words followed by their matching digit

```
>> string.scan(/(\w+)(\d)/).flatten #=> ["test", "0", "chance", "1", "already", "0", "again", "4"]
```

and turn it into a hash.

```
>> Hash[*string.scan(/(\w+)(\d)/).flatten] #=> {"test"=>"0", "chance"=>"1", "already"=>"0", "again"=>"4"}
```

Then it's a simple case of asking the hash for the value that matches a particular word.

String.scan is powerful but often overlooked. For Perl programmers it's similar to using the `m//g` pattern match.

Here's a little different way to populate the hash:

```
>> string.scan(/(\w+)(\d)/).inject({}){|h,a| h[a[0]]=a[1]; h} #=> {"test"=>"0", "chance"=>"1", "already"=>"0", "again"=>"4"}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, that is very interesting, thanks.  I actually reversed string and word in my update, so /word\d+/.match(string) returns "chance1" seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into words, then find which one includes the target word.

```
string.split(' ').find {|s| s.index word}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = string.match Regexp.new(word + '\d')
```

This concatenates `word` with `\d`(the regexp for a single digit) which in your case would compile to `/chance\d/`, which would match the word 'chance' with any single digit after it. Then it would check the string for a match, so you'd get the 'chance1' in the string.